# Nginx negating condition/ if else

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've came into situation where I cannot find a way around it, neither with tons googling.

```
valid_referers none blocked something.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    rewrite ^ /leech.jpg;
    expires epoch;
}
```

Everything works fine so far, but I want to create if referer is valid to expire max; I couldn't find how to negate if statement or create else in nginx configuration. I tried:

```
else {
    expires max;
}
```

or (notice exclamation mark)

```
if(!$invalid_referer){
     expires max;
}
```

but it doesn't work as it works in almost everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to make one setting default and other one turned on by condition:

```
expires max;

valid_referers none blocked something.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    rewrite ^ /leech.jpg;
    expires epoch;
}
```

Comment: if ($invalid_referer = 0) is working for me, thanks to guys from #nginx. But your solution is even better